# 1Z0-007 exam question

Tags: sql, plsql

Question:
In which four clauses can a subquery be used? (Choose four.)

A. in the INTO clause of an INSERT statement

B. in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement

C. in the GROUP BY clause of a SELECT statement

D. in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statement

E. in the SET clause of an UPDATE statement

F. in the VALUES clause of an INSERT statement

Answer: **B, D, E, F**

But I think right answers are the following: **A, B, D, E**  BUT NOT **F**. Is not it so???

Comment: If there was "instead of the values clause of an insert statement"...the answer would be true but "in the VALUES clause of an INSERT statement" means like that insert into tb2 values(select col1,col2 from tb1) and it is wrong!!!!


I read somewhere that if i didn't choose these answers(B, D, E, F) i will get wrong answer but why???

Comment: `INSERT INTO tb2 (col1) VALUES((SELECT TOP 1 col1 FROM tb1))` should be just fine. Note that subqueries are always put in parens.

Comment: when i try :

insert into tb2(col1) values((select col1 from tb1))  It Works, but

when i try:

insert into tb2(col1,col2) values((select col1,col2 from tb1)) Doesn't Work!! (I exactly know that "select col1,col2 from tb1" returns one row)  why???

Comment: aren't you in breach of the exam taking conditions by posting the question?

Comment: what do you mean??? can you explain clearly am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @kupa, it doesnt work because it has to be a **scalar** value, as I wrote.

Comment: @Mitch, I guess the breach would not be to ask about why the correct answers are different than expected (in fact, kupa seems to be trying to understand and learn), but rather how he or she knows the correct answer in advance.

Comment: @Lucero thank you very much..you seem to be very good person.. and you have taught me very good thing,thank you for this 
Just i want to clarify that i found some questions posted on the forum and was surprised by their answers.. that is why i wrote here...
@Mitch maybe be you shouldn't have downvoted my post, just because of i found this questions on the internet

Comment: @kupa: this question hasn't been downvoted

Comment: @Lucero: I'm referring to posting the question. I think if you examine the conditions of taking these exams, it explicitly states you will not publicly disclose the questions (or legal parlance to that effect)

Comment: @Mitch, I do see your point, and while I don't know the conditions for that exam I agree that this is likely to be so. However, I was looking at it from the perspective of learning from it, which doesn't seem wrong; kupa maybe should have "anonymized" it instead of specifying the exam where it comes from.

Comment: @Mitch I meant another question(about synonyms) you downvoted.
(But I erased it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loot at! ...I found something very important,which proves my assertion...

**Subqueries in Other DML Statements**

Subqueries can be used in DML statements such as **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **DELETE**,

and **MERGE**. Following are some examples of subqueries in DML

statements.

To update the salary of all employees to the maximum salary in the

corresponding department (correlated subquery):

```
UPDATE employees e1

SET  salary = (SELECT MAX(salary)

     FROM  employees e2

     WHERE e1.department_id = e2.department_id);
```

To delete the records of employees whose salary is below the average

salary in the department (using a correlated subquery):

```
DELETE FROM employees e

WHERE salary < (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employees

      WHERE  department_id = e.department_id);
```

To insert records to a table using a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO employee_archive

SELECT * FROM employees;
```

To specify a subquery in the VALUES clause of the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO departments

       (department_id, department_name)

VALUES ((SELECT MAX(department_id)

         +10 FROM departments), 'EDP');
```

***You can also have a subquery in the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements in place of the table name***. Here is an example:

```
DELETE FROM

(SELECT * FROM departments

 WHERE department_id < 20)

WHERE department_id = 10;




INSERT INTO (SELECT department_id, department_name

FROM departments

WHERE department_id < 20)

VALUES (35, 'MARKETING');
```

1 row created.

Answer (score 4):

No, **B, D, E, F** sounds correct.

Why do you thik A should be valid? The INTO is designating a target rowset, which cannot be a subquery. And in F you can use subqueries which return a scalar value just fine.

Comment: insert into (select col1,col2 from table1) values ('k','k') COMMIT; it will insert rows into table1 try


and can you tell me what do you mean when you say "And in F you can use subqueries which return a scalar value just fine"

Comment: If subquery in the `INSERT INTO` is defined such that the columns to be added are unambigious, it may accept it; but that is just a special case and not a general rule. Try making the query more complex (for instance by adding a function call, like `SELECT GETDATE() AS col1, col2 FROM table1`), and it won't work anymore. Regarding scalar values, I already explained in the comment to the question.

Comment: Great!!! I understand what you mean,answer "A" is not true because it doesn't work always especially for your case "SELECT GETDATE() AS col1, col2 FROM table1"  But the question "can be used" doesn't mean that in some case can be used it is not forced that always must be used

Answer (score 2):

First of all we must acknowledge that a subquery returns a set of value tuples (rows): `{(value_1_A, value_1_B, ...), (value_2_A, value_2_B, ...), ...}`

**A** - The `INTO` clause expects a table name, not a set of values so you may not use a subquery. Note that this is not similar to **B** because you are allowed to query an anonymous table (a set of rows returned by a subquery), but it makes no sense to insert values into an anonymous table that will not be used.

**F** - The VALUES clause of the `INSERT` statement expects exactly what I said a subquery returns, a set of values.

The right answer will be **B**, **D**, **E** and **F**.

Here's some more info on subqueries: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php

Comment: insert into (select col1,col2 from table1)
values ('k','k')
COMMIT;

it will insert rows into table1 try

Comment: I tried on (MySQL) and it did not work. Unfortunately I can't test on Oracle, but I think your query makes no sense. It may work, but it makes no sense. (Arguments can be found in my answer.)

Comment: Oracle (and other RDBMS) allow writable views, and basically the same rules apply to the subquery here. But as I wrote in my answer, the subquery cannot generally be used there but only if it basically uses the same structure/rules as a writable view.

Answer (score 1):

Subquery can be used in the INTO clause of an INSERT statement. So A also correct answer.

The below query works:

```
insert into (select name from emp) 
values ((select 'sunil' from dual));
```